# How to disable built-in CSS styling of PrimeFaces components?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am using `JSF` version 2.1.9 and `PrimeFaces` version 5 in my project.  I like a lot of the PF component that are built on top of the simpler JSF base versions (like `p:dataTable` vs `h:dataTable`), however, what annoys the hell out of me is that using PF (at least in our setup) comes with default CSS styling whereas the plain JSF components do not.  I would like to disable this default styling in the PF components so that all styling that shows is because I set it explicitly and not because PF comes like that.

Is there a way to disable this unwanted styling of PrimeFaces components?